# “Even if it is...so be it” vs “Whether it is... so be it” vs “Whether it be”

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammaticality, expressions

What’s the difference between those expressions?

For example:

> Well, there is something between you and me **even if it is** the distance, **so be it**!

> Well, there is something between you and me **whether it is** the distance, **so be it**!

> Well, there is something between you and me **whether it be** the distance!

Comment: The second and third seem incomplete to me. Except as the object of something like _know_, _ask_ or _the question_, "whether " usually wants an "or" alternative.

Comment: Colin Fine, you think nothing remains between us (in our relationship), but I assure you that one thing remains which is the distance. Is the distance acceptable to you or is this not, either?

Comment: the meaning of 2 and 3 is reasonably clear, but I don't find them idiomatic. If you added _or not_ after "distance" they would work (though No 2 still feels awkward unless there's a comma before "whether"

Answer (score 1):

A useful phase here is **if nothing else**.

From Merriam-Webster:

> **Definition of *if nothing else***
> —used to say that something is probably
> the only thing that is true, acceptable, desirable, or certain because there are no better/worse possibilities
> // The food is cheap, if nothing else.
> // If nothing else, there's the party (to go to) this evening.
> // If nothing else, you should send him a card.

You could then word your sentence like:

> There is still something between us. If nothing else, there's the distance!

I think it may sound better to use a more concrete term than just "the distance" here, maybe like:

> There is still *something* between us. If nothing else, there's the Atlantic Ocean!

> There is still *something* between us. If nothing else, there's 1000 miles!

Comment: I agree. Exactly the same thing I want to say you suggest by using ‘If nothing else’. Thank you. I voted for your answer.

Comment: Justin, do not cut off connections with me. If nothing else, there’s the enemity. 

Comment: I’ll nurture the temperament of surrender. If nothing else, be it even detachment of your habitude!

Answer (score 0):

The **first sentence** means:
There is something between you, also if it is the distance.

**Second one:**
There is something between you. It be the distance, or not.

**Third:**
There is something between you. It be the distance, or not.

---

[**So be it**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/so-be-it) is used to say that you have to accept the situation as it is.

[**Whether**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/whether) means that the speaker is doubting about something: *I'm not sure whether you like it.* means *I'm not sure if you like it or not.*

Comment: I don’t think “even If” means “also if” in that expression

Comment: @Jay Ho could be, but I think the first gives less attention to “may” or “not” than the other two — in the first sentence, it doesn’t matter if (not).

Comment: "It be the distance" isn't standard English - perhaps you mean "it might be the distance".

Comment: rjpond, it’s good English. The “be” form sounds a little dated, formal, and literary. “whether it be...” is subjunctive allows for the possibility of any of the types of work.

Comment: @JayHo You could get away with it after "whether" (in some circumstances) - but here, Romein77 is using "It be the distance, or not" as a full sentence, and this is definitely, unambiguously wrong.  I know he is paraphrasing a "whether" expression, but it is still incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any of these sentences are particularly natural the way you wrote them.

> Well, there is something between you and me even if it is the distance, so be it!

This one is the closest one to sounding correct.  But "so be it" doesn't really fit here.

I think "Well, there is something between you and me, even if it is the distance" would be better, or "Well, there is something between you and me, even if it is just the distance" (which would mean the same as "Well, there is something between you and me - if nothing else, the distance" - a wording suggested in another answer).

> Well, there is something between you and me whether it is the distance, so be it!

This should really be "Well, there is something between you and me, whether it is the distance or something else" or "Well, there is something between you and me, whether it is the distance or not".  You can't really go without an "or" here.

> Well, there is something between you and me whether it be the distance!

This would just about work if you added "or not" on the end.  That said, "Whether it be" is borderline archaic.